# PyQt5 - pyuic5 module PyQt5.uic not found

Tags: qt5, python-3.4, pyqt5

I've upgraded my deveolpment environment from python-3.2/ Qt-4.8/ PyQt4 to python 3.4.2 / Qt5.3 / PyQt5.

Everything is Ok but the python source code generation with pyuic5.

When calling this commands I get the error

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named uic
```

The Qt uic program is located at

~/Qt/5.3/gcc_64/bin/uic

The PyQt5 pacjakge is located at

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5

Even if the PyQt5 environment is operational as runtime I can't build any new GUI interface, so I can't move forward with this application upgrade.

Any idea ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Look carefully at the two python-related file-paths: do you notice any discrepancy?

Comment: honestly not, as I don't know how PyQt and Qt and internaly works together. I have a user installation in my home directory for QT, and the python3 system environment upgraded from 3.2 to 3.4.2. It works for me with Python3.2/PyQt4 & Qt4.8 (in the home directory). Is it a problem with the QT5 version ? or have I missed something else ?

Comment: The `pyuic5` script is calling the python installed under `/usr`, whereas you installed PyQt5 under `/usr/local`. Whenever you build and install packages, you must always run the configuration scripts using the python executable for the specific python installation you are targeting.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the answer from @Akhil. The code below really helps me avoid the "module not found" problem, and successfully create a .py file from a .ui file.

```
 exec python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic youruifile -o yourpyfile -x
```

Comment: `os.system(pyuic5 youruifile > yourpyfile)` suddenly starting giving me module not found, after working just fine for a long time. The above code helped me solve it.

Answer (score 6):

```
call python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x filename.ui -o filename.py
```

this one worked for me (28th june 2017, PyQt5, python 3.6, win10, 64bit)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I had installed PyQt into a virtual environment and the issue was the the pyuic5 script was not using the python interpreter for that virtual environment.

So I opened up the pyuic5 script

```
exec pythonw2.7 -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic ${1+"$@"}
```

to

```
exec python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic ${1+"$@"}'
```

This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I just recently encountered this issue when setting up external tools for Qt Creator. I know its not exactly what you ran into but it produces the same error. I don't like the idea of modifying files in my anaconda/bin directory so I didn't want to implement either of the other answers.

What I did find is that when you are setting up an external tool Qt Creator operates as if you are working in a new environment (i.e. your PATH is not the same as your development path). What I found is that you need to set the Environment field to have the same path as your development environment. This occurs by default when you setup Build and Run Settings for your project, but not for external tools.

Like @ekhumoro said in his comment **You must pay attention to your PATH** at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are a Mac user and I had faced a similar issue.

It seems you'll simply have to provide the full path of the `pyuic` file (for me, it was under a hidden folder `usr` in the home directory: `/usr/local/Cellar/pyqt/5.10.1_1/bin/pyuic5`).

In your terminal, change directory to where the `*.ui` files( which you wish to convert to a `*.py` file) lies.

So for instance, if you have a Qt designer file saved by the name `untitled.ui` on your desktop, put in the following command in your terminal:

```
Amars-MacBook-Pro:Desktop amaradak$ /usr/local/Cellar/pyqt/5.10.1_1/bin/pyuic5 -x untitled.ui -o untitled.py
```

Hope this helps...
Cheers

Comment: suggested one edit, formatting is very important to make answer readable. Also spaces between paragraphs that focus on different parts, help a lot the reader. Sometimes the same content can get +1 instead of -1 only for formatting choices. Regards

Comment: Thank you Fabiano, I hope this makes it a little more readable. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: i've been searching for 2 days and all problem solved!

First Rule in Python: **Don't use .XML this is not Java instead use .PY** for me i don't need uic at all

Let's begin, my pyuic5 actually there is no in PyQt5 folder instead in Scripts Folder

```
C:\......Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyuic5.exe
```

you have to make sure that the `yourFile.ui` is in the same location of your `pyuic5.exe`

Follow the pict below, you will be understand:

How to convert ui to py for easy way

[image]

uic not found solved

[image]

it works like a Charm !

Hi everybody , see last pict, i just converted `ui` to `py` for the first time in my life !