# to import pyqt5.uic, do I have to install pyqt5-tools first?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

to import pyqt5.uic, do I have to install pyqt5-tools first?

[image: screenshot.jpg]

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\77140\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\myaddon> pip freeze | grep PyQt
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.10.1
PyQt5-stubs==5.15.6.0
PyQtWebEngine==5.15.5
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5==5.15.2
```

But My python version is 3.10, from [pyqt5-tools offical site](https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/), it doesn't support python 3.10, is it why when I exec `pip install pyqt5-tools`, always get the below error?:

Thanks a lot.

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\77140\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons21\myaddon> pip install pyqt5-tools
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/b7/70/a25aab849a5e38ae78716acde1f917a14d9d819c8600bbb8cf536781f7c5/pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\77140\appdata\roaming\anki2\addons21\myaddon\venv\lib\site-packages (from pyqt5-tools) (8.1.3)
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/36/b8/a255b8160e863678aa7d559a4c8c33b5448a6e270992d1464ec9f87ed633/pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/88/ca/a9cb4816479940d1e0c94c683418c2cc4b4bc2955cd3c5754179a5f95040/pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/e5/cb/34b583ce53ca66803cfe904b11ae87633b1e98121a2a54583674514ae29b/pyqt5_tools-5.15.3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.3
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/6e/86/d715e71771cece0e060f2ebab20f3ded067b08a0927dfb3143530cae8098/PyQt5-5.15.3.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\77140\appdata\roaming\anki2\addons21\myaddon\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel   
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
     
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\77140\appdata\roaming\anki2\addons21\myaddon\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\users\77140\appdata\roaming\anki2\addons21\myaddon\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "c:\users\77140\appdata\roaming\anki2\addons21\myaddon\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel   
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\77140\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fnfit907\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
        File "C:\Users\77140\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fnfit907\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\77140\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fnfit907\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 594, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\77140\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8c05wpmz\pyqt5_4b97949f3a094e468dd52d10bb2e71c4\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\77140\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fnfit907\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\77140\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fnfit907\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\77140\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fnfit907\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629864/pyqt5-pyuic5-module-pyqt5-uic-not-found

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. But when need use PyCharm to run it, How should I set it?

Comment: As you've already found out, you cannot install pyqt5-tools with Python > 3.9. If you need it, downgrade Python.